# File tree in OracleSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a basic file system tree that consists of two tables:

```
folders
     =======================
     id_f    | (PK)
     name    |
     parent  | (FK references id_f)
```

and

```
files
     =======================
     name    |
     content | (File content / text)
     parent  | (FK references id_f)
```

I need to make a query that will display the filesystem as a tree view like this:

```
ROOT
   DIR1
      file1
      file2
   DIR2
   DIR3
      file
   DIR4
      DIR5
      DIR6
```

Any help on how to achive this output? Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/queries003.htm ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try this.  Can't test it myself at the moment.

```
SELECT LPAD(' ', (level-1)*2) || name
FROM (
  SELECT id_f, name, parent FROM folders
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, name, parent FROM files
  )
START WITH parent IS NULL
CONNECT BY parent = PRIOR id_f
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. I tested it, runs great with the exception of the `lpad` usage which I fixed in your post. The first argument is the character that is used for padding, not the value to be padded

Comment: @a_horse -- I believe you're mistaken there -- the character (actually, string) to be used for padding is an optional third parameter -- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2017.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link - I wasn't aware of that. But for some reason your initial statement did not pad the name at all (it only printed 2 characters). Feel free to rever it to your initial version. Sorry for the confusion.